# Need to create a custom table in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am a newbie in WordPress.
I have a requirement to create a custom database table in WordPress to store some data. Which would be the best way to do it?

1. Create from the backend MQSQL?
2. Is there a plugin available to create the database table?

Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Either way could be fine. What exactly is your problem? Have you looked at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: It could be great that you write a plugin to create the table if not exists, and in the same plugin do the code that you need for this database. What is your need ? Why do you want another table ?

Comment: My requirement is to capture data such as name, address,DOB etc and then display the data in a query screen. Hence the question as to which approach would be better.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you don't use plugin for that kind of thing. The easiest way is to do it with phpMyAdmin if you have it on your cPanel.